# Ajax call not working after adding remote command

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have this code:

```
<p:inputText value="#{cars.mymethod}">
<p:ajax event="keyup" listener="#{cars.mylistener}" update="picklist"/>
</p:inputText>
 <p:picklist id="picklist" value="#{cars.carvalue}" var="{cars}" 
  itemValue="#{cars}"/>
```

This was working fine till now and I was able to see the values getting updated in picklist. But I added a remote command recently for another need and after which this ajax call is not at all getting executed or loaded.

```
<p:remoteCommand name="rcName" actionListener="#{cars.remoteAction}" 
 process="@this" partialSubmit="true"/>
```

And 
What is the actual Problem with the code? Why this is not getting executed? Is calling remote command a bad way in Primefaces? 
Basically I am calling remote command here:

```
$(document).on('click', '.ui-datepicker-next', function () {
rcName();
}
```

These are the ways I tried out:
1. Added Partialsubmit="true" in p:ajax 
2. added async="true" 
Still no sign of ajax executing. What actually gets wrong here? I am completely struck

Comment: If you put `alert('got here');` in your `.ui-datepicker-next` on click is it even firing?  That tests whether your onclick javascript is being call at all.

Comment: Not sure if your problem is that `p:inputText/p:ajax keyup` does not trigger any more, or your `remoteCommand` does nothing? Please edit your question to provide a [mcve] and enhanced description on observed vs. expected behavior. This increases your chance of getting a useful anser.

Comment: Thanks melloware and selaron for commenting I will try out the suggestions and will post out a clear example. Thanks again for Responding